# How do I do either a SumIf or SumProduct function with VBA coding to Sum accross multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

My current formula in the cell is:

`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Regions&"'!$C:$C"),$B4,INDIRECT("'"&Regions&"'!AI:AI"))),"")`

Annoyingly the AI:AI will not change the reference cell when I copy across (only down)

I would like to take the formula out of the cell and have it calculate through a module instead. Any ideas would be fantastic thanks

Comment: Check out the [WorksheetFunction object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) it provides all the methods that are available in cell formulas. Try something on your own, and if you get stuck or errors come back with the code you tried and ask a question to it (see [ask]). • To your issue, obviously `AI:AI` does not get changed becaus it isn't an address but a string used in `INDIRECT`.

Comment: We'd like to help, but more details are needed, i.e., what exactly do you want to achieve. Examples are welcome, because it's not easy to understand from text.

Answer (score 1):

In this formula

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Regions&"'!$C:$C"),$B4,INDIRECT("'"&Regions&"'!AI:AI"))),"")
```

`INDIRECT` is using a string/text that **looks like** an address but since it is only a string (you can see that it is in quotes `" "`) it doesn't change when it get's copied over to another cell. Actually that is the purpose of `INDIRECT` (that it **does not** change).

Example:

1. `=SUM(A:A)`
   here `A:A` is a real address that will change if you copy it to another cell.
2. `=SUM(INDIRECT("A:A"))`
   here `"A:A"` is a string and this will **not** change if you copy it to another cell!

So you can workaround that by replacing

```
INDIRECT("'"&Regions&"'!$C:$C")
```

with

```
INDIRECT("'Regions'!" & ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(C:C)) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROWS(C:C),COLUMN(C:C)))
```

**How does that work?**

- `ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(C:C))` returns `$C$1`
- `ADDRESS(ROWS(C:C),COLUMN(C:C))` returns `$C$1048576`

Together this will be `$C$1:$C$1048576` which is the same as `C:C`. And because here `C:C` in your formula is a real address and not a string it will change if you copy it over.

**INDIRECT is volatile!**

Note that `INDIRECT` is a volatile function. That means it recalculates everytime any value of any cell changes.

Example:

1. `=SUM(A:A)`
   this will only re-calulate if a value in `A:A` changes if a value in `B:B` changes it doesn't affect recalculation of this formula.
2. `=SUM(INDIRECT("A:A"))`
   this will re-calculate on **any** value change even if a value in `B:B` changes it re-calculates.

Therefore the heavy use of volatile functions should be avoided because it slows down your worksheet **a lot**.